# How to copy/paste from a local machine to a remote server

Tags: vimrc, register

I am trying to copy text onto my clipboard on a local mac and paste it onto a remote linux server. I am able to yank the text from my local machine onto my machine's clipboard using:

`"*yy`

And I can copy/paste this into another buffer/window/program locally. It also says at the bottom:

> 76 lines yanked into "*

So I know it's working.

However, when I try and copy/paste that remotely it doesn't appear to copy it over from my system's clipboard and says `"Nothing in register"`. Here is a video showing copying it over locally (which works) and remotely (which doesn't): https://gyazo.com/4f67eead477a2b054455c5f0f16ab32b.

What would be the proper way to copy over to a remote server?

Comment: This is not trivial and depends on the systems used. You might need to fiddle around with `ssh -Y` or `ssh -X`. You need to forward the X11 connection, so access to your clipboard is possible. But this tends to become a rabbit hole. So it might be easier to use `netrw` from your local vim and edit remote files.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I didn't know `netrw` could access remote files. How does that work?

Comment: it basically uses ssh to copy over files